# Android Fragments Crash

Tags: android, crash, android-fragments

I have just started learning Android Fragments. Please help my why my following program is crashing.

One Activity contains two fragments and  each fragment has only one button to display. 
I tried to follow the example in Head First Android Development...BUT :(

Activity which contains fragments

```
public class FragmentsContainer extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.fragmentscontaineractivity);
    }
}
```

Layout of fragment container

```
   <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <fragment
            android:name="com.example.nasaimage.ImageOne"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <fragment
            android:name="com.example.nasaimage.ImageTwo"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="2" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

First Fragment and layout

```
 public class ImageOne extends Fragment {

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,
                ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            return inflater.inflate(R.layout.imageoneactivity, container, false);
        }
   }

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Second Activity and Layout

```
 public class ImageTwo extends Fragment {

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState){

             View view =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.imagetwoactivity, container, false);

                Button button = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button1);
                button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                  @Override
                  public void onClick(View v) {

                  }
                });
                return view;
        }
    }


    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Which version of Android are you targetting? I ask you this because if you are not testing your code 3.x or above you need to extend the FragmentActivity class from the support package instead the normal Activity class.

Comment: Post your LogCat errors so we can see what is happening.

Comment: Doesn't it bother you that those two buttons have the same id? I think you should change it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should include the support library found [here](http://developer.android.com/tools/extras/support-library.html) then make your `Activity` extend `FragmentActivity`.

Only Android 3.x and above added the `FragmentManager` and `Fragment` support into the base `Activity` class.

Comment: Guys i am targetting all version , from 2.3 to 4.1... nothing is working... :( @ wasyl the problem is not replated to buttons id. . i have just rcreated to layout with single objecy in it for testing

Comment: I Have also added the support liberary for this project..... Can some one just copy this code in your eclipse and run... you will see the problem

Comment: A crash log could be useful for us.. not everybody has the time to reproduce your issue but we might have ideas to solve it if you could give us all the clues we need..

Comment: D/AndroidRuntime(585): Shutting down VM
W/dalvikvm(585): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a13300)
E/AndroidRuntime(585): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime(585): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.nasaimage/com.example.nasaimage.FragmentsContainer}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #7: Error inflating class fragment
E/AndroidRuntime(585): android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java) E/AndroidRuntime(585):  android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java

Answer (score 1):

Why are you using this approach, there's a smarter approach you can use...
After pressing a button, or menu option or navigation drawer item the fragment can be invoked like this way:

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager
                    .beginTransaction();
            FragmentExcel fragmentS1 = new FragmentExcel();
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.content_frame, fragmentS1);
            fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

Then the the fragment class can be like this where there are three buttons with specific functionalities:

```
public class FragmentExcel extends Fragment {    
    Button buttonCat, buttonBudg, buttonExpense;
    DBHelper db;

    public static Fragment newInstance(Context context) {
        FragmentHistory f = new FragmentHistory();    
        return f;
    }

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {    
        if (container == null) {
            return null;
        }

        RelativeLayout mLinearLayout = (RelativeLayout) inflater.inflate(
                R.layout.fragment_excel, container, false);

        db = new DBHelper((getActivity().getBaseContext()));

        buttonCat = (Button) mLinearLayout.findViewById(R.id.buttonCategoies);
        buttonBudg = (Button) mLinearLayout.findViewById(R.id.buttonBudgets);
        buttonExpense = (Button) mLinearLayout
                .findViewById(R.id.buttonExpenses);

        buttonCat.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {    
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                db = new DBHelper((getActivity().getBaseContext()));
                String tableName = "categories";
                db.exportDataIntoCSV(tableName);

                Toast.makeText(getActivity().getBaseContext(),
                        "File is saved in tour SDCard storage",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();    
            }
        });

        buttonBudg.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {    
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //Do whatever you want    
            }
        });

        buttonExpense.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {    
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //Do whatever you want              }
        });

        return mLinearLayout;
    }
}
```